# Typescript declare module export

Tags: typescript

1. I have npm package A, npm package B，application C
2. There is an interface in A

```js
interface Node {
  name: string;
}
```

3. I expected to extend this interface in npm package B, so I did

```js
declare module "A" {
  interface Node {
    user: string;
  }
}
```

4. It can be used in package B, but the question now is, how do I get Node -> user in application C

```js
import { Node } from "A";

let node: Node = {
  name: "!",
  user: "!" // Type Error
}
```

(I can use A B in C, but how should I make the extension in B take effect)

Comment: Maybe you can try re-exporting `Node` from package B and importing it from there in your application instead of importing it from package A?

Comment: @cdimitroulas Thank you for your comment. My ultimate goal is to expect B or D E F ... to extend the interface Node of A respectively (without considering the conflict of repeated definitions), so that the website C can have type hints when it is used, maybe it cannot be realized

Answer (score 0):

I changed to the following

A:

```js
export interface Node extends Foo.NodeExtension {
  name: string;
}

declare global {
  namespace Foo{
    interface NodeExtension {}
  }
}
```

B:

```js
declare global {
  namespace Foo{
    interface NodeExtension {
      user: string;
    }
  }
}
```

C:

```js
import { Node } from "A";

let node: Node = {
  name: "!",
  user: "!" // Right
}
```